# host github pages from /dist folder in master branch

Tags: github, deployment, build, gulp, github-pages

I was trying to publish my -username-.github.io repository to github pages but my `index.html` is inside `dist` folder.

I cannot use `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` because this is meant for project pages, not user/org pages.

All I want is, github to treat dist as root directory for hosting user/org page.  Please help.Thanks

PS: I don't want to do redirection hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it this way.

GitHub pages can be hosted from either:

- the `/` folder in the master branch
- the `/` folder in the gh-pages branch
- the `/docs` folder in the master branch

But the user pages must be built from the `/` folder in the master branch.

**TIP**

Code on another branch than the master. After every push to this branch, build it in any CI/CD tool and push it back to the master branch.

Comment: Explained here, https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

Answer (score 23):

#### [Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) (very limited)

While you *can* select a folder as the source for gh-pages, you can *only* do so for the `/docs` directory at the parent level, and you *still* have to actually commit the built files in order to do so, which means you'll have to override the `.gitignore` and commit them twice

[image]

#### Automated Deploy Scripts

If you're using npm, there are a couple packages that handle publishing sub-directories to gh-pages.  Install with option `--save-dev` to add it to your `devDependencies`:

- [**push-dir**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/push-dir)

  ```bash
  # install
  $ npm install push-dir --save-dev

  # usage
  $ push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages
  ```
- [**gh-pages**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages)

  ```bash
  # install
  $ npm install gh-pages --save-dev

  # usage
  $ gh-pages -d dist
  ```

In either case, if get a command line tool working for you and get it configured with the right options, you can alias it in your `package.json` like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "npm run build && gh-pages -d dist"
}
```

**Further Reading**:

- [Deploying a subfolder to GitHub Pages](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490)
- [Deploy Vue to GitHub pages-the easy way!](https://medium.com/@codetheorist/vue-up-your-github-pages-the-right-way-955486220418)

Answer (score 1):

If like me you would prefer to upload to github pages using subtree's in git you can use something like the code below.

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```