# Not able to host on github-pages due to error with React Router

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

Here's the link to my portfolio website that I'm trying to deploy on github-pages: https://github.com/AbhishekM2001/AbhishekM2001.github.io

The site is working properly when deployed locally but when I try to deploy on github pages I get the error: 'Syntax Error,Unexpected <' on the line where React Router is implemented in index.js file. I've also used Hashrouter instead of Router but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The application build is on the `dist` folder, but the site has been hosted based on `root` folder.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42501045/11566161

Comment: @ShriHariL ,thanks a lot for the reference link. Setting dist as the root folder using gh-pages module solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else stuck on the issue,
I had bundled all my files using parcel bundler so the index.html in `dist` folder was being served instead of the index.html in `root` folder.
Using gh-pages to set dist as root folder worked for me.

Refer the commands in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42501045/11566161
Courtesy: Shri Hari L in comments.